# coldfusion 9 VAR issue whilst using <cfset>

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am getting very confused.

I have a set of variables...

```
<cfset cataloge_menu_1 = "menu item 1">
<cfset cataloge_menu_2 = "menu item 2">
<cfset cataloge_menu_3 = "menu item 3">
```

I have a URL ID so what i'm trying to do is output the above variable base on the URL ID, so I have the following...

```
<cfset cathead = "cataloge_menu_"&url.typeID>
```

and the following output...

```
<cfoutput>#cathead#</cfoutput>
```

But instead of outputting "menu item 1" or menu item 2" depending on the URL ID, it outputs "cataloge_menu_1" or "cataloge_menu_2".

What I need to output is the "menu item X" not the "cataloge_menu_X".

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you use a variable that looks like `<cfset cataloge_menu = ["Menu item 1", "Menu item 2", "Menu item 3"]>`. Then `<cfset cathead = cateloge_menu[url.typeID]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish it using `Evaluate()` function. This is how it works:

```
<cfset cataloge_menu_1 = "menu item 1">
<cfset cataloge_menu_2 = "menu item 2">
<cfset cataloge_menu_3 = "menu item 3">
<cfset url.typeID=2 />

<cfset cathead = Evaluate("cataloge_menu_"&url.typeID) />
<cfoutput>#cathead#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I'd avoid using evaluate for this.  Simply use the bracket notation with the variables scope like what Adam did in his answer.

Comment: Yes, go ahead with @Adam Solutions for the associative array concept. It is best to use when you have dynamic typed variables.
Read this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7fdf.html

Answer (score 8):

What this is doing:

```
<cfset cathead = "cataloge_menu_"&url.typeID>
```

Is simply making a string containing `"cataloge_menu_1"` (etc). And the this:

```
<cfoutput>#cathead#</cfoutput>
```

Is simply outputting that string.

If you want to access a variable called `cataloge_menu_1` then you can't simply output a string containing that variable name and expect CF to guess you mean "look for a variable with that name and output that instead of just the string". You need to tell it to output that *variable*.

Unscoped variables are - by default - put in the variables scope. So to fetch a dynamically named variable from the variables scope, you use associative array notation to reference the variable via a string containing its name:

```
<cfoutput>#variables[cathead]#</cfoutput>
```

PS: it's perhaps a language thing (ie: the code is not in English), but do you mean `cataloge` or `catalogue` (or I s'pose `catalog` if you must)?

Comment: Hi Adam, many thanks for you detailed explanation, I have tried using an associative array as suggested but i get the following error...You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members.

Comment: also, sorry for my english - yep, it should be catalogue. :-)

Comment: It should also tell you which line of code (and accordingly which variable) you are misunderstanding the contents of. Standard troublehsooting technique here is to dump out the variables in question and confirm they contain what you think they contain.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just try this:

```
<cfset cathead = VARIABLES["cataloge_menu_" & url.typeID]>
<cfoutput>#cathead#</cfoutput>
```

Or you could just output the dynamic variable:

```
<cfoutput>#VARIABLES["cataloge_menu_" & url.typeID]#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I prefer this solution as I always follow the square bracket notation to refer to a dynamic variable in any scope, it's clean and doesn't has any associated overhead as with the `Evaluate()`.